# web2py veiwing auth() itmes

Tags: authentication, web2py

Hi I am working on a web2py project.

I use auth object to create login feature 
And using the following code

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [Field('address')]
```

So whenever, an user sign up for an account, the person need to put address.

What I would like to do is display the address in default/index.html when the user login to my application.(the user can view his own address only, not the others)

Do I need to deal with db.auth_user??
I have no clue...

Can you help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is logged in, the entire user record is available in `auth.user` (which will have a value of `None` if the user is not logged in). So, to display the address in a view:

```
{{=auth.user.address}}
```

You could also retrieve the user record from the database via `db.auth_user(id)` or `db(db.auth_user.id == id).select().first()`, but using `auth.user` is more efficient, as it is stored in the session and therefore does not require a database query.